# Windows 10 Installer USB not showing up on GRUB

Tags: grub2

Ubuntu USB shows up just fine on GRUB menu, but Windows 10 USB won't show up. Any ideas as to why?
My Windows Installation USB is not modified, and comes from the Microsoft website, in the picture below:
[DESCRIPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfNkP.png)

Comment: What does this question have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: You do not boot an installer from grub (normally). You boot from UEFI boot menu. Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drives and only in BIOS mode to MBR partitioned drives.

Comment: How do you "boot" from UEFI?